# Clear/Empty IFRAME which gets fed it's src by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I got an iframe inside a modal which starts on "about:blank" and does get fed src's by jquery.

This works alright already, but when the iframe src is set to change, there is always a delay where the modal will still show the old content, while loading the new.

How can I instantly clear the iframe before a new src is given?

Here some code:

```
$(function() {
      $('a.modal-k2-<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>').click(function() {
            window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_title').text('<?php echo $author->name . ' - ' . $this->item->title; ?>');
            if (window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src') != '<?php echo $itemlink; ?>') {
                window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src','about:blank');
                window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src','<?php echo $itemlink; ?>');
            }
            window.top.$('#modalHolderK2').modal();
            return false;
      });
    });
```

It seems that the "window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src','about:blank);" is not executed fully before the new src is passed to the iframe.

I guess there is an easy solution but I didnt find anything which worked for me yet.

I just want to avoid the modal to show old content when a new one is called.

Comment: you're missing a closing quote `.attr('src','about:blank');`

Comment: yea alrdy fixed. (I had already deleted that command, because it wasnt working, just added it back to illustrate the problem or what I am trying to do)

Answer (score 13):

$("#iframe").contents().find("body").html('');

Comment: This works for friendly iframes but not with iframes with src's on different domains.

Answer (score 10):

To give the `iframe` chance to render the the blank page before loading the next one, consider setting a timeout that updates the frame source to the final URL when fired, e.g.:

```
window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src','about:blank');
setTimeout(function() {
    window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src','http://www.yoururl.com/');
}, 100);
//....
window.top.$('#modalHolderK2').modal();
```

Comment: with a timeout it works! The users see a blank modal when the src is switched, before the new loads.

How can I get it to wait with modal display until the iframe is loaded? I probably cannot use it because the iframe takes 2-3 secs to load and that delay would be too long, but I want to try it out.

Comment: @user1873194, I don't know what what `$(..).modal()` does, so can't comment on that. Is it a jQuery plugin?

Comment: @user1873194, BTW rather than using a blank page, have you considered loading a simple place-holder page (perhaps with a throbber) to indicate that the main page is loading? If you are regularly using this modal dialog then the browser would cache it and so it would load almost instantly.

Comment: That modal method is from Twitter Bootstrap, it opens a Lightbox which has do be defined somewhere in code. The idea with a place-holder "loading" page is great! Instead of about:blank ill create a slim html page with just "loading content.." and display that whenever the iframe is switching sources.

Comment: Glad to help @user1873194. If you're happy with this solution please accept the answer so that others can find it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('#iframid').attr('src', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forcing a needless 100 ms wait on the user, you can just `.remove()` the iframe and create a new one:

```
    $(function () {
        $('a.modal-k2-<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>').click(function () {
            window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_title').text('<?php echo $author->name . ' - ' . $this->item->title; ?>');

            //cache reference to reduce querying for elements:
            let $modalIframe = window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe');

            if ($modalIframe.attr('src') != '<?php echo $itemlink; ?>') {
                let $iframeParent = $modalIframe.parent(); //where we'll put the new iframe

                //remove the iframe:
                $modalIframe.remove();

                //create a new iframe and append it to $iframeParent
                $modalIframe = $('<iframe></iframe>').attr('id', 'modalHolderK2_iframe').attr('src', '<?php echo $itemlink; ?>');
                $modalIframe.appendTo($iframeParent);
            }
            $modalIframe.modal();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Updating src would push a state to browser history.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be simply to create a div that looks just like an empty iframe. Then display it in the first line of your function, and in the onLoad event of the iframe, hide the div again. Then you don't have to deal with how the iframe renders while it's loading its new content at all.

As requested, a quick mockup of my proposed solution (I'm assuming you can read jQuery calls?).

```
<div id="hider" style="display:none"></div>
<iframe id="myIFrame" onload="$('#hider').hide()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateIframe(newUrl) {
      $('#hider').show();
      $('#myIFrame').attr('src', newUrl);
    }
</script>
```

Now just use CSS to position the div such that it perfectly overlaps the iframe. You show the div to hide the iFrame, then when the iframe has finished loading, its onload event hides the div again, showing the new content.

Comment: create a what? you mean iframe i guess?

Do you maybe have an example?

Comment: @user1873194 Sorry! I wrote "div" and "iframe" in < and > characters, and the forum code evidently doesn't render text that's wrapped like that.

Comment: I understand it now, yea that would probably work too, but its a bit too forced I think, if not necessary.

I tried a timeout on the load of the new src like suggested above, that works fine, but maybe I'll try your approach too if the delay the users get is too long.

Answer (score 0):

How about just resetting the src to about:blank before loading the next page?

```
var ifr=window.top.$('#modalHolderK2_iframe');
if (ifr.attr('src') != '<?php echo $itemlink; ?>') {
ifr.on('load',function(){
    // need to remove onload
    $(this).off('load');
    this.src='<?php echo $itemlink; ?>';
    window.top.$('#modalHolderK2').modal();
});
ifr.attr('src','about:blank');
}
```

Comment: oh ok. But you're not waiting until about:blank is loaded, you overwrite it immediately. This might be the issue.